# When to pass an object instead of parameters?

Tags: javascript

At what point in time is it better to create an object of parameters instead of sending multiple parameters to a function? What do good programming practices dictate?

Comment: As soon as there are too many to remember their order, or when they are optional independently.

Comment: @Bergi, that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Passing a litteral object instead of several parameters makes it possible to add new parameters to the function, without the need to rewrite it's declaration. When there are multiple parameters, that's easier.

Also, when you call the function with parameters, you have to remember all of them, and their order. By using objects and properties, you name each property/parameter and set it with a value, the code is more readable.

Comment: The code calling the function is maybe more readable (many modern IDEs provide parameter hints), but I would argue that it makes the actual function definition less readable. You now have to read the whole function to see which parameters it expects (unless you use parameter destructuring). Another downside is that the function cannot be curried anymore for working in a functional style.

Comment: @Pierre, good explanation

Comment: @subarachnid Currying only works well when having a defined number of parameters in a suitable order. You still can do partial application with object parameters, like `const partialO = (fn, defaults) => (args) => fn({...defaults, ...args});`

Comment: @Bergi, true. I just noticed another problem with using a param object: You cannot trivially rename parameters without changing every function call as well.